# Linq Expression Fails when I use OrderBy property.Length or mix Include,OrderBy and AutoMapper ProjectTo<T> Clause

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2, automapper-collections-ef-core

Asp.net MVC Core 2.2 App crashes when a LINQ expression that uses a combination of Include, `Orderby` and AutoMapper's `ProjectTo<T>` clause. Below is the exception raised by the app.:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.PropertyExpression' to type
>   'Remotion.Linq.Clauses.Expressions.QuerySourceReferenceExpression'.

The behavior of this LINQ expression is unpredictable because at times it works and others it breaks. I have tried both Eager and Lazy loading but still, get the same error.

```
recordList = await db.SchoolProfile
                    .Include(i => i.Category)
                    .Include(i => i.District)
                    .Include(i => i.SchoolAddress.Address)
                    .Include(i => i.SchoolAddress.Coordinates)
                    .OrderBy(o => o.Name.Length)
                    .ProjectTo<SchoolProfileViewModel>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
                    .ToListAsync();
```

The same error is thrown even without `Include` Clause:

```
recordList = await db.CurricularActivity
                    .OrderBy(o => o.Activity.Length)
                    .ProjectTo<CurricularActivityViewModel>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
                    .ToListAsync();
```

Removing `Activity.Length` seems to work but why having it breaks the code but the same query works elsewhere?

I would, therefore, appreciate some guidance in resolving this.

I would greatly appreciate learning why this is happening and understanding how to resolve this such that I can write more efficient and error-free LINQ expressions

Comment: Most likely an EF Core issue. Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html). Run that as a LINQ statement, without AM. You should get the same result.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu thank you for the link, the order of execution has an impact, so I changed the query to do projection first and then LINQ expression and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the order of expression matters the most, I have this working without errors @Lucian Bargaoanu, thank you for the [link](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html) to automapper documentation. Always start with **Projection** using `ProjectTo<T>` followed by `LINQ` expression.

```
recordList = await db.SchoolProfile
                    .ProjectTo<SchoolProfileViewModel>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
                    .OrderBy(o => o.SchoolName)
                    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: In EF6 it works without the Include-s. I'm not sure about EF Core, but try it :)

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I think EF6 has Lazy-Loading turned on by default and that's not the case with EF-Core, with ef-core you need to add Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies package and you can activate it globally in ConfigureServices on DBcontext options as follows : options.UseLazyLoadingProxies or use the context instance to turn it on and off as follows : dbcontext.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = Boolean value. So for now, EagerLoading using Includes is a convenient option for me.

Comment: Lazy loading is not relevant here. Look at the execution plan. By default ProjectTo will fetch everything in your view model. That's why Include is not needed.

Comment: Unless you actually map to types that contain real database entity types, those `Include()` calls don’t actually do anything, so you can just get rid of them. No idea why it would break if you do use them in a certain order though.

Comment: Thank you for the kind feedback, I can confirm that it works without ```Include()``` clause, however the error is raised when I do ```.OrderBy(o => o.SchoolName.Length)```. If I remove ```.Length``` it works just fine. So I remain baffled by this.